# Angular routerLink with lazy loading

Tags: angular

I apologize if this question has been answered. I haven't found a problem like mine.

I have an angular app that has two 'pages'. Pages = normal components with modules. 
And I have a bunch of 'components' that are connected in one module.
( Here is the file structure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Z8z.png )

Now, in the `app-routing.module`, I use lazy loading to load the two pages. Like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/user/user.module').then(mod => mod.UserModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/admin/admin.module').then(mod => mod.AdminModule)
  }
];
```

This works well. In the user page I load the main-menu component.  `..<app-main-menu></aapp-main-menu>...`

**PROBLEM** - But now, I want to add `routerLink="/hotels` to a button in the main-menu component, in the user-page, so when the user clicks the button the page will load a different component, item-list. (not main-menu)

I tried adding a new path in the `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
  {
    path: 'item-list',
    component: ItemListComponent
  }
```

But I get an error saying that

> Component MainMenuComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

The reason for this error is because the item-list.component is loaded into the user-components.module.ts, which is called in the user.module.ts (main module that the page loads).

So the global question is: How can I set a routerLink to a component when using Lazy Loading (Because the component I want is declared in a specific module).

Comment: how can two lazy loaded routes have the same path?

Comment: @PierreDuc The admin page has a `path: 'admin'` in its module.ts. So when you load page/admin, it loads the page :)

Comment: you should remove it there, and add it to the app-routing

Answer (score 0):

Kinda fixed the problem by calling the module that has the component in the app-routing.module.ts

```
  {
    path: 'list',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/user-components/user-components.module').then(mod => mod.UserComponentsModule)
  }
```

The user.module has:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent
  }
];

...
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
```